# What is an association bonus?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stackexchange

Some user in the main page has 101 points without any questions or answers, because of an association bonus.  Could someone please explain what is that?

Comment: They have some... "business" associates. Don't ask too many questions, or else. :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are already a member of a Stack Exchange site, when you join another site, you get an association bonus of 100 reputation on the new site.

From [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> You gain reputation when you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: **+100** on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)